# Automatically connect to wifi network?

Tags: networking, wireless

I'm using an ODROID C1+ and need to connect to a wireless network. I have an open network I want to connect to, but every time I boot up, I need to manually reconnect.

Where do the known networks get recorded, and how do I edit my config to automatically reconnect to networks I've previously used?

I don't want to restart the network service every time I boot... Updating my kernel is NOT an option right now. How can I solve this issue of mine?

Answer (score 0):

First go to network manager on the top pannel and go to **edit connection** and delete all the connections under wifi section
Now you change `ifupdown(wlan0)`

To do so open terminal and type following command

```
sudo gedit /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf
```

type in your password and a window will open now check 
if **[ifupdown] managed=false** then change it to **true**
then save the file and type **exit** in terminal

Now open the terminal and type

```
 sudo service network-manager restart
```

this will restart your network manager.
Now connect to your wifi and do a system restart this will hopefully connect your wifi after every boot.